# How to integrate jenkins with selenium?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration

In my work location, we are creating automated web application tests using selenium web driver. Now we want to integrate it with Jenkins continuous integration tool to run the tests automatically when a new build is pushed to the server. How to do this implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a Maven `pom.xml` file in a new project directory that includes
   all the dependencies you need to get the project going.
2. From the command-line, run `mvn clean install` to download the
   dependencies.
3. Install PhantomJS from `phantomjs.org/download.html`. Make sure
   phantomjs is accessible from the command line.
4. If you have not done so yet, create a test.
5. Run the test. At the prompt, type: mvn test The test will run using
   PhantomJS and output the results to `target/surefire-reports` in a
   JUnit XML format that is understood by Jenkins.
6. Make sure PhantomJS is installed on all the Jenkins Nodes that will
   run the tests.
7. Create a new Jenkins job and set it to run after a build is
   deployed.
8. Save the job, run it and view the test results.

Comment: Thanks for the edtion